# Problem with bypass anti-bot system while deploying an application with Express.js and Puppeteer on Render.com

Tags: javascript, express, puppeteer, render.com, anti-bot

I'm working on a small application with `Express.js` using the `Puppeteer` web scraping library. I wanted to deploy the application on *render.com*, but I'm encountering errors that don't occur locally. Specifically, the error is: `"Error: No element found for selector: #login"`. I've been suggested that it might be a bot detection system recognizing `Puppeteer`. I've also captured a screenshot with Puppeteer for confirmation.

To prevent the bot from detecting the use of Puppeteer, I've followed a series of steps found on forums, YouTube, and Stack Overflow. I've used the `Puppeteer-extra library`, added `randomized viewport size`, and changed the `user-agent`, but despite all, I continue to get blocked. I would like to ask if there's another way to bypass the anti-bot system or if perhaps I might be doing something wrong.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());


//this is a part of the function

console.log("Entrato in fetchData");
  const url = "https://web.spaggiari.eu/cvv/app/default/genitori_voti.php";
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    { headless: "new" },
    {
      args: [
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--single-process",
        "--no-zygote",
      ],
      executablePath:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
          ? process.env.PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH
          : puppeteer.executablePath(),
    }
  );
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log("page creata");

  //Randomize viewport size
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    height: 3000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
    hasTouch: false,
    isLandscape: false,
    isMobile: false,
  });

  await newpage.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  );
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

  //Skip images/styles/fonts loading for performance
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", (req) => {
    if (
      req.resourceType() == "stylesheet" ||
      req.resourceType() == "font" ||
      req.resourceType() == "image"
    ) {
      req.abort();
    } else {
      req.continue();
    }
  });

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
  console.log("pagina caricata");
  await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

  await page.waitForSelector("#login");
  await page.type("#login", await codicePersonale);
  console.log("codice personale inserito");

  await page.waitForSelector("#password");
  await page.type("#password", await password);
  console.log("password inserita");

  await page.screenshot({
    path: "./screenshot.jpg",
  });
  console.log("screenshot fatto");

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" }),
    page.click(".accedi"),
  ]);

  await page.screenshot({
    path: "./screenshot2.jpg",
  });
  console.log("screenshot fatto");
```

[Screenschot with puppeteer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raLbS.png)

Comment: What's your local internet access situation - are you using a connection with a fixed IP, or a dynamic one? If the latter, then changes in your local IP might simply prevent them from "catching on", whereas repeated requests over a longer period of time coming from the same static IP address of your render.com server might trigger a block ...